# Integration with microsoft teams via API Postman

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, postman, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I try to integrate with microsoft teams i follow this documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/use-postman

One of require request to get access token fill `"Username" and "Password"`
I don't have any idea how to get this 2 value and from where!

Where i keep him blanc i receive :

```
The request body must contain the following parameter: 'username'.\r\nTrace ID: ......
```

Any idea?

Comment: Your POSTMAN collection needs username/password. To access any protected resource like Microsoft Graph API then follow the steps: (1) [Register an Azure AD application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-register-app-v2) based on your AAD workflows. Make sure it has necessary Graph permissions [2] Make sure you have M365 tenant/account, has username/password [3] Configure POSTMAN as per above AAD workflow and update the values from two above steps (Azure AD app details, tenant info, username, password) [4] Start using the POSTMAN collection... You're good to go.

Comment: @Dev i got this error : The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID

Comment: @tino alberto-If you go to Azure Active Directory in the new portal, find your app registration there and click Grant Permissions under the Required permissions blade.

Comment: Yes Tino please follow the steps as updated by @Rama-MSFT above. It will help you to grant permissions/consent and then give a try.

Comment: yes solved thank you guz but i have another error in grant permission, why i can't grant all in microsoft graph permission?

Comment: i got this error : Grant consent failed with error: Value length '8118' is out of the valid range of '1' to '8000' for property 'DelegationScope'.

Comment: Glad it worked :)

Comment: With respect to the below error, i remember a related [thread](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/40100899-failed-to-admin-consent-for-microsoft-graph-api-fr?edit=1). Sounds like its consent related error or related to admin consent.

Comment: bro thank you for helping me! all work fine please put your first message to vot it , helped me! @Dev

Comment: @tinoalberto, glad to hear that as well. 

Let me move this to answer. Consider upvoting and accept the answer. So it can be useful to others as well :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

POSTMAN collection needs username/password. To access any protected resource like Microsoft Graph API then follow the steps:

1. [Register an Azure AD application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-register-app-v2) based on your AAD workflows. Make sure it has necessary Graph permissions
2. Make sure you have M365 tenant/account, has username/password
3. Configure POSTMAN as per above AAD workflow and update the values
   from two above steps (Azure AD app details, tenant info, username,
   password)
4. Start using the POSTMAN collection, get the token from AAD, make call to Graph API/Teams.